# Google Cloud Speech API and metadata industry naics code of audio

Tags: metadata, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

When using the Google Cloud Speech API does adding metadata ex. the industry naics code of audio ex. https://www.naics.com/search, influence the speech recognition? ie, would adding the naics code improve for recognition inline with the indicated vertical?

Answer (score 0):

No, they do not have this feature.

Comment: You can add metadata, that feature exists. My question is if it is actually influencing speech recognition

Comment: They just collect it for further purposes, not used right now.

Comment: Heh. I was curious if it was influencing or just an attempt to get the data labelled correctly for use! Thanks :)